# HTTP Error 500 Joomla Site in Windows Server 2012 IIS

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012, joomla

I am trying to migrate a Joomla 1.5 website from Linux to Windows Server 2012. I tried to use the Web Platform Install. It installed most components, PHP, IIS Url Rewrite, etc except Joomla itself. I keep getting an access denied error when asking for the password for MySQL instance.

Anyways, I just copied over the website files from Linux to Windows Server. Setup the configuration.php to access the correct database. I have also migrated the database content over to the new server. When accessing the administrator page, site login page, static pages, etc. it works fine. When I try to access the jDownloads page, I get HTTP Error 500. There's not much information I could get from it. There are no errors in EventViewer. Any ideas what I can check? Did I miss something during setup? The jDownloads page is accessed from a menu link that takes me to this link index.php?option=com_jdownloads&view=viewcategories

I wanted to upgrade the Joomla site after migrating it over to the new server, but I don't want to do it yet until I get everything working. That way I can easily identify what broke during upgrade and what broke during migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having the same issue, I updated the jDownloads component to the latest version (1.8.2) for Joomla 1.5 and it fine. Just need to start the upgrade process from 1.5 to 3.x for Joomla.